# Conditional GOTO in bash, skipping from one function to a later-called one

Tags: bash, function, shell, while-loop

Consider the below pseudocode.

- If `http_code` is gerater than 400, I want to run all the functions in the `while read` loop.
- Otherwise, flow should skip directly to `func_ws8`.

This doesn't work as-written (`continue` complaints that it isn't valid except inside a loop, and `goto` doesn't exist at all); what equivalent code could I write to achieve the desired effect?

```
#!/bin/bash

func_ws206 {
  if [ $http_code -gt 400 ]
    continue
  else
    goto func_ws8
  fi
}

# stub functions; in the real code, these actually do something.
func_ws250 { :; }
func_ws8 { :; }
func_ws302 { :; }
func_ws65 { :; }

while IFS= read -r msisdn
do     
  echo "$msisdn"      
  func_ws206
  func_wc250
  func_ws8
  func_302
  func_ws65         
done < es_msisdn.txt
```

Comment: I've tried to rewrite this to be more focused and clear. Hopefully it succeeds in representing what you meant to ask?

Comment: BTW, note that `$http_code` should be quoted as `"$http_code"` so you aren't passing `[` invalid syntax if it's empty, _or_ if it word-splits to more than one argument. Or you can use `[[` or `((`, which don't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like the below, where we use a global `goto` variable, and a wrapper that checks its value before each function call:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT sh, so we can use bash-local syntax

func_ws206() {
  if (( http_code <= 400 )); then
    goto=ws8
  fi
}
func_ws250() { echo "In ws250" >&2; }
func_ws8()   { echo "In ws8" >&2; }
func_ws302() { echo "In ws302" >&2; }
func_ws65()  { echo "In ws65" >&2; }

run_funcs() {
  goto=
  for funcname do  # default for loop behavior iterates over "$@"
    if [[ $goto ]]; then
      if [[ $goto != "$funcname" ]]; then
        continue
      else
        goto=
      fi
    fi
    "func_${funcname}"
  done
}

while IFS= read -r msidn; do
  run_funcs ws206  wc250 ws8 302 ws65
done
```

Comment: I would'nt use <= for 400 http code, because 400 is an error but < 400

Comment: @GillesQuenot, sure, but it's the OP's logic. They used `-gt 400` (rather than `-ge 400`), so they clearly want 400 to be treated in the same class as 200 or 399. Whether that's the right thing for them to want is their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use exit statuses for flow control. The caller of `func_ws206` should decide what gets execute next, not `func_ws206` itself.

```
#!/bin/bash

func_ws206 () {
  [ $http_code -gt 400 ]
}

# stub functions; in the real code, these actually do something.
func_ws250 () { :; }
func_ws8 () { :; }
func_ws302 () { :; }
func_ws65 () { :; }

while IFS= read -r msisdn
do     
  echo "$msisdn"      
  if func_ws206; then
    func_wc250
  fi
  func_ws8
  func_302
  func_ws65         
done < es_msisdn.txt
```

Comment: Definitely the better practice in general, but sometimes there's a legitimate call for a "goto"/skip-to-x; I've used it for restore points to make a script restart at the right place after interruption, for example.